# How to upload and play songs in react js using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component here that should allow a user to play the current songs and add new ones from their computer. This is the code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const SongListUI = () => {

    const [songs, setSongs] = useState([])
    const [oneSong, setSong] = useState('')
    const [Artist, setArtist] = useState('')
    const [src, setSrc] = useState('')

    const addSong = (oneSong, Artist) =>{
        setSongs([...songs, {title: oneSong, artist: Artist, source: src, id: Math.random(0,1)}])
    }



    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        addSong(oneSong, Artist, src)
    }

    return ( 
        <div className="hi">
            {
                songs.map(song =>{
                    return(
                        <div key={song.id}>
                            <h4>{song.title}</h4>
                            <audio controls>
                                <source src={song.source} type="audio/mpeg" />
                            </audio>
                            <h3>{song.artist}</h3>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>addSong</label>
                <input type="text" value={oneSong} onChange={(e) => setSong(e.target.value)}/>
                <input type="text" value={Artist} onChange={(e) => setArtist(e.target.value)}/>
                <input type="file" value={src} onChange={(e) => setSrc(e.target.value)}/>
                <input type="submit" value="Add a Song"/>
            </form>


        </div>
     );
}

export default SongListUI;
```

The problem is whenever I try to upload an mp3 file from my computer through the file input I get an error :Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/fakepath/Black%20Sabbath%20-%20Paranoid%20(Full%20Album).mp3 
How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Chrome as your browser? If yes, Then probably chrome blocks your local file access for some security matter. Which is this part :
"file:///C:/fakepath/Black%20Sabbath%20-%20Paranoid%20(Full%20Album).mp3"

Try to upload your file in some cloud servers E.g: http://yourserver/your/path.mp3

Or try to place it in somewhere in your react root folder then access it like this:

```
const source = ./yourfilename.mp3

<source src={source} type="audio/mpeg" />
```

Comment: Okay so, here is what I've done, I created a cloud database and firebase Firestore, and it's still being uploaded to the data base as a string with C:\fakepath\name of the file.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, So you're trying to upload a music somewhere in your cloud storage right? So you have you check your syntax or the extension that you are currently using for uploading your mp3s. The problem here is the string right? and also C:\Fakepath\filename reads it locally not in your cloud

Comment: Yes, so basically what I'm trying to do is, I've linked my react app to the firestore cloud database, and then I coded a function by which a user can add a new song from a normal jsx input form, and when they add the song, which is an object of title artist and source (source is where the mp3 file is on my device) and when this song object is added to the data base, another function fires and renders the songs inside the database to a jsx list. but that didn't correctly, the audio tag in which the song supposed to be played didn't work, because the source in the data base was a string C:\Fa...

Comment: `<input type="file" value={src} onChange={(e) => setSrc(e.target.value)}/>` this line converts the value of your file upload into the path where it is placed. You need to manipulate the string of it before sending it to the DB. You can do a lot of ways and techniques or you can use this `setSrc(e.target.value.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop())` then when getting your data you also need to concatenate the source link of your cloud e.g `const firebaseUrl="http://mycloudservice.com/"` then add your string `source={fireBaseUrl + songs.source}` Hope that helps